# My background is dark and now i cant see my app names. How do i make the words white?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8, color

My background is dark and now i cant see my app names. How do i make the words white?!

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: What is your launcher?

Comment: This seems to be a non-Samsung default home screen, icons, and the like. Since it seems you are using a customization pack, the capability for screen text color is probably within it. See settings within whichever one is active.